# Content line length was exceeded the maximum length 990 characters

Tags: html

While I try to upload a html file, I get error saying

> " Content line length was exceeded the maximum length 990 characters at line number".

And I see that line is using more than 1700 characters in single line. 
When I split this long line into multiple lines and upload is getting success.

What I don't understand is: 
Do we have any restriction for the number of characters allowed on a single line ?? If so how much. 
Don't we have a option that html adjust this automatically ??

Comment: are the error your getting not related to what you are doing with the html rather than the html... please adjust title and question to reflect this. ie. can you save on your a desktop and html file which has more than 90000 chars... probably... which means your question has nothing to do with html and chars. rather limits of what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Line length of what, in particular? If you mean that you have an entire HTML file on one line, which is very possible but not recommended, then you'll want to split your code onto separate lines. It helps with readability or if someone is reviewing your code, for example. If it's the length of a really long string, then you can drop it down to the next line and it'll still behave like you expect it to.

Answering the question, however, it looks like there's a character limit of 990 characters per line. Adjusting this automatically, which some services do (like e-Mail servers) could cause corruption to your HTML content, so you will want to add line breaks yourself.